# devops rest api: understanding permissions

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm new to the world of REST and devops.
My goal is to list all the permissions in a specific project (new projects have 7 permissions, the important ones to me are the project admins and project valid users).
My end goal is to list, add or remove Azure AD groups to these permission groups.

I can successfully query a list of projects and all teams. I can list the members of a team.
But I can't find how to interact with the permissions.
I was expecting to find it in the GroupEntitlements or MemberEntitlements.

Can someone help me in the right direction?
A second question I will have after this, is how to add an AAD security group to a permission? How do I find out what the correct identifiers are?
I also don't really grasp the concept of a team; if you can put everyone in a permission?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following apis:

1. [Get the list of groups in a Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

`GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1`

2. [List the Security Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security%20namespaces/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#all-security-namespaces)

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/securitynamespaces?api-version=6.0`

3. [Get ACL/Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=6.0`

4. [Edit/Set Group Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20entries/set%20access%20control%20entries?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=6.0`

5. [Unset/Delete Group Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20entries/remove%20access%20control%20entries?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

`DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=6.0`

Here is a useful documentation you can refer to:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10072318/SzfAyS4s

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is your issue solved?